# Unity Framework

Tags: .net-framework

I was thinking of learning Unity Framework (for .net Dependency injection). When I searched for it on google I came across this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650320.aspx). It says that the content is retired. I just want to know is that Unity framework has retired. If yes what has replaced it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the content on the pages is retired and hence maybe outdated. The framework hasn't been retired

Comment: Thanks for your reply and also for editing the post...Was worikng thru night so not in best of senses :)...Can you please point me to the links where I will get the latest content...my concern was that the link says - Retired Content
This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.

Comment: @Any - I'm not aware from where you can get the latest documentation -  just go through it, and if you have any specific questions on that try asking at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Any. As I understand it, Unity has become part of the 'Microsoft Enterprise Library' see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572(v=PandP.50).aspx . T